# Unique ID for Google/Facebook Oauth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

Are there any unique and unchanging tokens available to me from Facebook and Google?

Once I get the tokens and user information back from Oauth login, it is then up to me to search my database for a user with that email and create an account if it does not exist.

The problem is, even if the oauth token and therefore email is authentic, I still want to use a second token in the database query when I look up the users.

Do Google and Facebook have any unique ID fields that I can bundle with the email when I create users to aid in the security of my login process?

p.s. I am using Mean stack and passportjs if there are any known validation or token generation packages that might help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both providers expose a unique user ID.

- Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint):

  > [...] you can safely retrieve and use the *user's unique Google ID* from the
  >   **sub** claim.
- To retrieve the Facebook user_id, make a call to:

  > `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token=xxx`